# Flat shaded THREE Phong Material renders with lots of noise

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm running into an issue in THREE when rendering extremely steep faces with a flat shaded material and viewing it at a steep angle. Here's what it looks like on my machine:

[image]

The example scene here (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dQEzmG?editors=1010) demonstrates the issue. It's composed of a plane that is modified so it has a ramp from `z = 0` to `z = -100000` that is rendered with a flat shaded phong material.

```
var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 10, 10, 10);
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ side: THREE.DoubleSide, color: "#ffffff", flatShading: true });
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
plane.rotation.set(Math.PI/2, 0, 0);

var posArr = geometry.attributes.position.array;
for (var i = 0; i < posArr.length / 2 - 3 * 6; i += 3) {
    posArr[i + 2] = 100000;
}
geometry.computeVertexNormals();
```

I'm only seeing this on my Macbook Pro laptop:

- Chrome 70.0.3538.1210 64-bit
- OSX 10.13.6
- Intel Core i7
- Radeon Pro 560 4096 MB

I know that flat shading in THREE uses the `OES_standard_derivatives` extension so I'm not sure if it's related to limitations in the extension. Is this a known issue? Is it a problem with THREE? Or an issue with the platform?

Thanks!

Comment: What are you trying to do by increasing the .z position to 100,000? Why don't you just declare `PlaneBufferGeometry(10, 100000, 10, 10);`? You're just botching the geometry with the way you're running your `for` loop, and you get triangles overlapping each other.

Comment: @Marquizzo The data I'm working with extends out to large values -- this is just a simplification of what I'm trying to achieve. I'm aware that I can work around the problem but I'd prefer not to and that doesn't answer why this is happening. There are no overlapping triangles here and this isn't z-fighting. The triangles have not been "botched" -- the z values of half of the vertices have just been changed. You can change the 100,000 value in the code to see that this is just a plane modified to have a kink in it.

Comment: Ah, my mistake. You're right, it's just a plane turned into sort of a Z shape. My best guess is that it's a GPU float precision bug, and you did find a limitation to the `OES_standard-derivatives` extension because when I bring the displacement down below `1000`, it renders as expected. codepen.io/marquizzo/pen/OaejpX Maybe adding more subdivisions along the stretched out segment would fix it?

Comment: That's kind of what I expected but was hoping there was something more well documented about the limitations. Are you able to repro the problem on your machine? Can I ask what type of computer you're seeing it on? I'm only able to see the issue on the laptop I listed. Thanks!

Comment: Macbook Pro Retina 15-inch Mid 2015. Running an AMD Radeon R9 M370X. Funnily enough, my ancient iPhone 5 renders it correctly.